# Which lifecycle hook to use for initialization?

Tags: vue.js

In the example below I use `created` lifecycle to subscribe to event service. Is it a normal practice? Is there a more appropriate way or lifecycle method to do this kind of stuff?

```
const ViewComponent = {
  data(){
    return {
      pathname: window.location.pathname
    }
  },
  created(){
    eventService.on('routeResolved', (route) => {
      this.pathname = route.pathname
    })    
  },
  computed: {
    component () {
     return routes[this.pathname]
    }
  },
  render (h) { 
    return h(this.component) 
  }
}
```

Comment: `mounted` is another option, and better if your service expects the component's DOM to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which lifecycle method you use for initialization depends entirely on what you need access to. If you need to manipulate the DOM in any way, you cannot do that until the `mounted` lifecycle event. For setting up an event handler like you are in the question, using the `created` lifecycle event is perfectly fine.

Mainly for one-time initialization actions, you will choose either `created` or `mounted`. If you need something done every time the component receives new properties you might use `beforeUpdated` or `updated`.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) for a full description.